# На чем делать админку для небольшого проекта?

Tags: php, bootstrap, framework, админка

Доброго дня, сообщество!

Делал сайты на джумле, потом на вордпрессе.
Вот теперь леплю лэндинги на бутстрапе, форма обратной связи, все дела, все замечательно.

А что если к этому лэндингу нужно еще посты прикрутить? Ну и вообще как то манипулировать контентом.

Подскажите что-нибудь легковесное, фреймворк какой нибудь php что-ли, где бы быстро и просто можно было сколотить админку, авторизация, mysql, вот это вот все.

Comment: Можно совершенно спокойно продолжать делать лендинги на `wordpress` + какой-нибудь кэширующий плагин типа `supercache`. Почему не подходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter - один из быстрых фреймворков, на нём сколотите админку. А вообще я с [xaja](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439378/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0#comment460604_439378) согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал для разметки использовать [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Красивые формы, и css практически писать не нужно будет. Так вы так и делаете, отлично.

А php-фреймворк выбирать по принципу "больше опыта, лучше знаете": Yii, Kohana или другие.